# Customize headers and footers

Tags: header-footer

I am writing my bachelor's thesis and the requirements for the first page are:

- in the header - name of the intitution
- in the center - the title of the paper
- in the footer - the town and the year

How can I do this?

I have tried to use the `fancyhdr` package and have managed to change the header, but that applies only on the pages in my paper, and not to the first page. The header does not have to be underlined. Also, on the next pages, I don't want any header to appear.

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{Institution}
\rhead{}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% \pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{empty}{%
    \fancyhf{}% removes h/f
    \fancyhead[c]{\Huge{Instituion}}% Your inst name
    \fancyfoot[r]{Town and year}
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% removes header line

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
    
\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}
    Here goes your abstract
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, only I have one more problem. My abstract is on a separate page and the header and footer also appear there. Can I erase them from that page?

Comment: I have edited my post

Answer (score 0):

or in this way

```
\pagestyle{fancy} % options: empty , plain , fancy

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0} % remove the line

\lhead{}\chead{Institution}\rhead{}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{}\rfoot{Town \& Year}
```